# Opacity if the mouse is moving

Tags: mousemove

I want to change the opacity of a div (like 0.5) when the mouse is moving
and when the mouse doesn't move change the opacity to 1
is that possible ?
Thank's.
Yves

Comment: Presumably you are asking about this in the context of objects displayed in a web browser? The only hint you give is "a div". Can you confirm?

Comment: You want to do it when the mouse is moving over your object or just moving no matter what part of the window is?

Comment: Thank's for the quick answers! I want to change the opacity (from 1 to 0.5) of a div when the mouse is moving anywhere on the browser window and when the mouse isn't moving change the opacity (from 0.5 to 1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply this to the element whenever the mouse is on the window, try this.

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv" style='width:100px;height:100px;background:rgb(255,0,0);'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).on("mousemove",function(e){
    $("#myDiv").css({opacity:0.5});
    clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
    window.myTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myDiv").css({opacity:1});
    },100);    
});
```

Basically, every time you move the mouse, you create a timeout but in the next movement, you cancel it. When you stop moving the mouse, eventually the timeout will execute and change the opacity of the element.

Comment: ojovirtual, that's the all thing ! thank's a lot, and thank's to everyone.Yves